# Linker error while I try to add asio to my C++ project

Tags: c++, mingw, asio

I have a following simple program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
    
int main() {
        
return 0;
    
}
```

And when I try to compile it with (mingw) I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Kamran\Desktop\Networking>g++ -I"C:\mingw\mingw\Include" -std=c++17 sou
rce.cpp
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Kamran\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4n0EJF.o:source.cpp:(.tex
t$_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh[_ZN5boost4asio6
detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh]+0x73): undefined reference to `
__imp_WSAStartup'
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Kamran\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4n0EJF.o:source.cpp:(.tex
t$_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS2_4dataE[_ZN5boost4asio6de
tail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS2_4dataE]+0x35): undefined reference to `__im
p_WSACleanup'
```

Any idea how should I debug?

Comment: Have you linked with the `ws2_32` or perhaps the `wsock32` library?

Comment: i can't find these files i didn't build the boost  just download a 7zip file and extracted it in my c drive

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have installed boost library on your Windows machine, you need to add `-lwsock32` in your command line.

Comment: i didn't build or install anything i just download a 7z file and extracted all the header files was inside the zip file and i try that didn't work same error

Comment: @milad ok. But have you tried with the given command?

Comment: Works for me using cmake

Comment: @AntonB great! Can you please accept it as a solution if it was helpful for you? It encourages new people like me here in SO to write helpful answers :)

Comment: @BZKN I don’t believe I can, only the original auther can do it.

Comment: @AntonB   yes, you are right....all good :)